# Creating Menu in SwiftUI - receive output message of [UILog] Called -[UIContextMenuInteraction updateVisibleMenuWithBlock:]

Tags: menu, swiftui, ios14

I'm attempting to create a pull down menu in SwiftUI , the menu seems to be fully visible on the device/simulator  and I can interact with it but I get the following message:

*[UILog] Called -[UIContextMenuInteraction updateVisibleMenuWithBlock:] while no context menu is visible. This won't do anything.*

Can anyone suggest a solution or help me understand the problem ? XCode Version 12.2 beta 4

```
struct AardvarkQuantity: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            Menu(content: {
                
                ForEach((1...5), id: \.self) {
                    Text("\($0)")
                        .font(Font.fontSFProText(size: 9))
                }
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Number of Aardvarks")
                    .font(Font.fontSFProText(size: 12))
                    .foregroundColor(ColorManager.itemRowLabelText)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I am aware this is just a debug message and doesn’t actually affect the use of the menu.

Comment: Darn it, you're right, the problem with getting the return value was elsewhere - thank. you so much for your prompt responses !

Comment: I got the problem while externalizing the Menu in a custom view. In that case the menu didn't continue to run as expected with a standard touch but with a long pressure.

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew and  pawello2222 both confirmed, the error message appears to be a log warning and code appears to be working
I ended up using the solution listed [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/using-ios-14s-menu-as-a-picker-in-swiftui-b036c772037).

Although I'm still not clear on how I should respond to the warning.

Comment: for me the message is output to log with a menu that doesn't work correctly. I got this error with a Menu in a composant I created.